# Error when creating a trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Having hard time with creating a trigger. Here is my code. I create 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE client_table
  (
  clientid NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  lastname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  firstname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  password varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
  email varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  phoneno NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
  zipcode NUMBER(6) NOT NULL ,
  street varchar2(60) NOT NULL,
  CHECK (email LIKE '%@%.%')
  );

CREATE TABLE location_table
(
  zipcode NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  country varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  region varchar2(60) NOT NULL,
  town varchar2(60) NOT NULL
  );
```

I add a constraint so that zipcode in client_table is a foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE client_table
ADD CONSTRAINT clirefzip
  FOREIGN KEY(zipcode) REFERENCES location_table(zipcode)
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Now I want to add a trigger, so that when i delete a location from location_table, it will delete all clients from client_table, that have the same zipcode as the location deleted. So I try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER location_delete
AFTER DELETE ON location_table
REFERENCING OLD AS old_buffer
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM client_table WHERE zipcode = old_buffer.zipcode;
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: "*does not work*" is neither an acceptable error description nor a valid Oracle error message. But why don't you just declare the foreign key as "on delete cascade"?

Comment: So what i have to do is write in my constraint something like: foreign key (zipcode) references location_table(zipcode) on delete cascade ?

Comment: Thx a lot man. It worked just fine. It's simple and effective. Sorry for my messy post. I'm novice. I'll try be more specific when posting a question next time.

Comment: Yes, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dcb1/1 Btw: `NUMBER(6)` is not a good choice for a ZIP code. There are many countries where the zip code contains non-numeric values and countries where you e.g. *have* to have a leading `0`

Comment: Thx for the tip, i'll keep it in mind. One more qustion, it might seem silly. How do i mark the question as answered now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi there has some syntactical errors in your code. I hope this code works . Thanks    

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER location_delete
    AFTER DELETE ON location_table
    --REFERENCING OLD AS old_buffer
    FOR EACH ROW
    begin
    DELETE FROM client_table WHERE zipcode = zipcode; 
    end location_trigger;
```

Comment: DO NOT TRY THIS !!! "zipcode =zipcode" always evaluates to true! You are going to delete the whole child table (or at least all the records where zipcode is not null)

Comment: it should have been DELETE FROM client_table WHERE zipcode = :OLD.zipcode;